# Document a multipart/form-data endpoint with Springfox

Tags: java, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a POST endpoint which receives a @ModelAttribute parameter. Everything is working ok, but the swagger documentation fails to have the descriptions, examples, etc.

I am using java 11, springboot 2.5.4 and springfox-boot-starter 3.0.0

Here is my code:

```
@Api
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
@Validated
public class MyRest {
    @PostMapping(value = "/{id}/bar", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Do nothing", notes = "This endpoint does nothing")
    public ResponseEntity<String> search(
            @ModelAttribute MyModelRequest request,

            @ApiParam(value = "Folder ID", required = true)
            @PathVariable String id) {
        // some business code
        return new ResponseEntity<>("lorem ipsum", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

MyModelRequest

```
@ApiModel
@Data
public class MyModelRequest {

    @ApiParam(name = "fileName", value = "The name of the image to be stored in database")
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "name model description", example = "summer picture", required = true)
    private String name;

    @DecimalMin("0.00")
    @DecimalMax("100.00")
    @ApiParam(name = "accuracy", value = "The required accuracy")
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Minimum required accuracy", example = "95.15", required = false)
    private BigDecimal accuracy;

    @ApiParam(name = "marginTop", value = "Top margin of the image")
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Separation between top item and the image", example = "300", required = false)
    private Integer marginTop;

    @ApiParam(name = "image")
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "The image to be stored", example = "vacations.png", required = true)
    private MultipartFile image;
}
```

And this is the generated swagger doc

[image: Swagger]

**UPDATE:** I noticed that if I change the `consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE }` for `consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }` or remove the whole "consumes" parameter from the endpoint, the documentation shows up correctly, however, doing this will make the fileupload fail.